# Type or namespace "IViewLocationExpander" could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement an IViewLocationExpander to add view paths to my MVC application, but I'm getting IViewLocationExpander is not found, and I can't figure out what reference I should add. My target framework is 4.5.1. The ASP.NET MVC nuget package has been added to the project. If I need to upgrade to a newer version of either the .Net framework or the MVC package, that's fine, but I don't want to stab around in the dark. Here's my class that doesn't compile:

```
public class AreaViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context) { }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        return new[]
        {
        "/AnotherPath/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "/AnotherPath/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        }; // add `.Union(viewLocations)` to add default locations
    }
}
```

Comment: If all you need to do is to locate views in non-default locations, have you thought about just implementing your own `MyViewEngine: RazorViewEngine`?

Comment: https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversity/blob/master/src/ContosoUniversity/Infrastructure/FeatureViewLocationRazorViewEngine.cs

Comment: Yeah, this just seemed more elegant, and I can't figure out why I can't get it working. :)